Pass SharePoint file directly to client with vgrem/phpSPO
I have connected my app (PHP) to a SharePoint library with vgrem/phpSPO. I'm able to download a file from the SharePoint to the server. But I want to be able to pass the download directly to the client without wasting disk space or RAM on the webserver itself.
Can anybody tell how "proxy" the download of a SharePoint file to the client?
